# How do I optimize repeated queries for pages in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2

On the side of each page on my site I list the other Pages in that Section. I also mark if the User visited or completed each page. Every time a page loads, Rails has to check the database to see if the User visited or completed each page in the Section, which makes displaying a page take longer. Is there a way I can speed this up?

Example: user visits page 2 and the sidebar loads. He then visits page 3 and the sidebar loads again, but likely with a different mark next to Page 2.

> ```
>                  Page 2
>                  ------
>
> - ✓ page 1     |     Main Content
> - > page 2     |    The quick brown fox...
> -   page 3     |
>      ...
> ```

Comment: turbolinks gem would help if I'm understanding what you are looking for. it has some caveats though. turbolinks is for front end pjax. for query caching using memcached with dalli

Comment: Is there a reason you are emulating browser behavior with the visited link thing?

Comment: What about the :visited CSS pseudo property?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few areas you could improve performance, both in database lookup and in rendering.

For rendering, you should look at [fragment cacheing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) the sidebar for visited links, although your scenario is a bit out of the ordinary in terms of keeping track of visited links in your app.

For each link in the side bar you could save a fragment that represents visited and unvisited, then the outer container could represent any permutation of visited and unvisited since it doesn't really matter which user it is when you display it. You will end up with a lot of various side bars for each of those scenarios.

For the database you could look at something like [identity_cache](https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache) and hold the list of users page visits in the cache to avoid unneeded lookups, invalidating when they hit a new page.

This is as good as I can get for such a broad question in relation to Rails and speed ups in general, which seems to be what the question is asking. There are numerous other platforms specific speedups that you can get by playing with different caching back-ends and servers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are keeping track of the pages they have visited and/or completed in a database table because this data needs to remain stateful.

If so, first off, make sure your table is properly indexed on the columns it needs to look up.

Then, cache the results in a sessions variable, so that you can retrieve it from there and only go to the database when necessary (e.g. something changes the state or a certain period of time lapses)